# visual of how to find the feature maps of two input with 3 filters in cnn

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

1st layer of CNN :
We have an input and we apply two filters on the input to get 2 feature maps.
now in my knowledge, we'll use these two feature maps as an input in 2nd layer of CNN.
if we apply 3 filters on these two inputs I know the total feature maps will be 3 because no. of feature maps = number of filters.
My Question :
How to do it visually.
In simple words, we have two inputs and we have to add three filters to these inputs. How would we do it?
question:
2 feature maps:

1. 4X4

   w11,w12,w13,w14

   ....

   ....

   w41,w42,.....,w44
2. 4X4

   u11,u12,u13,u14

   ....

   ....

   u41,u42,.....,u44

3 filters:

1. 3X3

   f11,f12,f13

   ....

   f31,f32,f33
2. g11,g12,g13

   ....
3. h11,h12,h13

   ....

[image: I want to do it just like the picture below]